# Sender dependent relay with transport maps in postfix

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp

We have some SMTP server in our company. We have transport maps in which we define what domains send to other smtp server. Now, we need sender dependent config for some users. The users are using same domain as in the transport maps table.

I tried sender_dependent_relayhost_maps but It is not working when transport maps enabled.

Idea, what I want:

All @companydomain.ltd forward to smtp in transport_maps table:

```
companydomain.tld            smtp:[smtp-server.tld]
```

exception (forward some users' mails to another smtp):

```
user@companydomain.tld       [another-smtp-server.tld]
user2@companydomain.tld      [another-smtp-server.tld]
```

Is there any sender dependent setting that overwrites the transport_maps?

Comment: if this is at user level, then define address forward for each address to any destination.

Comment: I am afraid transport_maps has the highest priority and it is hard-coded in the source code of postfix.